# Why do JTable accept Vector directly and not ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, vector, jtable

From my limited experience, Vector and ArrayList can be used in the same way, with the same methods (add, remove, etc)

In my school they only teach us to use ArrayList, but when we get to GUI creation, I found that the JTable constructor only accept Vectors or Object arrays and not ArrayList. Why is this the case?

Comment: `JTable` predates `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend on [Elliott's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622048/why-do-jtable-accept-vector-directly-and-not-arraylist/59622224#comment105407387_59622048):

#### Reason why? Precedence or historic reasons!

`Object[]` [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)s and [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) exist in Java since the beginning with Java version 1.0. When Sun introduced the GUI-framework [*Swing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) (which UI-component `JTable` is part of) to Java version 1.2  only these data-structures were available at that time.